# Save Ruby on rails session on ElastiCache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, redis, amazon-elasticache

I have a nice small social network type application in Ruby on Rails 3.2. I'd like to store the user's  session files in ElastiCache in amazon. Anybody has any advice on how to do this?

I have a redis-session-store gem to store sessions in redis is there a simple way to just store session information in ElastiCache?

Comment: I wonder if using dalli with memcache and modifiying config/initializers/session_store.rb works... I need to know if I have to do any special changes to the code so that it works on elasticache or I have to write special code for it to work there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ElastiCache is compliant with the memcache protocol. They speak the same lingo, so just configure your elasticache endpoint in rails, configure your session store, and it should Just Work.

Comment: Thank you, eventually I figured out this, but it didn't work . I'm just "lucky" like that, things that are supposed to work just don't. Anyhow. The files that need to be modified are config/initializers/session_store.rb and config/environments/production.rb, then adding the appropriate gems and it "should" work.